# this.props.children.map at react native is not working

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux

I want to render a child component from a parent component by passing to it one object from array of objects fetched from an api.

TypeError: this.props.posts.map is not a function

```
renderPosts() {
return this.props.posts.map(post =>
  <HomeCard key={post.id} postData={post} />
    );
  }
```

---

All the component:

```
class Home extends Component {
componentWillMount() {
  this.props.getUserPosts();
}

renderPosts() {
return this.props.posts.map(post =>
  <HomeCard key={post.id} postData={post} />
    );
  }


  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <View style={{ paddingBottom: 55 }}>
            <SearchBar />
        </View>

        <ScrollView>
        {this.renderPosts()}
        </ScrollView>

      </View>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
const posts = state.homePost;
console.log('posts', posts);

return { posts };
};


export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getUserPosts })(Home);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is because `this.props.posts` is `undefined` (empty or whatever default you have it set to) when `Home` being mounted. Since you aren't giving us any log outputs, it's hard to tell but this is a very common mistake.

The immediate fix is to give it a default value either where you define your initial state for your reducer or in `mapStateToProps`. The latter looking something like this (adapting your code):

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  const posts = state.homePost || [];
  console.log('posts', posts);

  return { posts };
};
```

While this will fix your error, another thing you need to correct is the common misconception that whatever is in `componentWillMount` will execute prior to mounting. This is not true and is one of the reasons that this lifecycle method (and `componentWillReceiveProps` and `componentWillUpdate`) [will be deprecated in the future](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/29/react-v-16-3.html#component-lifecycle-changes).

Your code here:

```
componentWillMount() {
  this.props.getUserPosts();
}
```

is asynchronous since you mention fetching this data. `getUserPosts` will fire but isn't guaranteed to complete before mounting. So while you think `this.props.posts` will be set to some value before rendering, that is not going to be the case. Hence why you are getting the `not a function` error message.