# React-Native: setState() for getCurrentLocation = null

Tags: firebase, react-native, location, state-management

I want to get the distance of my tasks, which are objects with lat lng values. They are saved in my firebase database.

Now my problem is, that I am setting the users current location in componentWillMount, by setState. But when I call getDistance from my async task (firebase query) the state of the users current location is null.

I think this happens because the operations are not in the same context. So I tried to dig into redux but could not master this topic.

How could I solve this?

```
      getDistance(latitude, longitude) {
        let c = geolib.getDistance(
          { latitude: { latitude }, longitude: { longitude } }, // strawa
          { latitude: this.state.latitude, longitude: this.state.longitude }, // sbg
          100,
          1
        );
        return c / 1000;
        //alert(c / 1000); // 25km
      }
    
      /*
          Get the Users current location
          iOS -> asks only one time for permission, so pay attention if disabled !!!
      */
      getCurrentLocation() {
        var loc;
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
          position => {
            console.log("Location Request - Position = " + position);
            this.setState({
              latitude: position.coords.latitude,
              longitude: position.coords.longitude
            });
          },
          error => this.setState({ error: error.message }),
          { enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 200000, maximumAge: 1000 }
        );
      }
    
      componentWillMount() {
        //this.getCurrentLocation();
        this.listenForTasks(this.tasksRef);
      }

  listenForTasks(tasksRef) {
    tasksRef.on("value", snap => {
      var tasks = [];
      snap.forEach(child => {
        // If Task_Type = 0 getDistance
        var distance = "";
        if (child.val().type === "0") {
          distance = this.getDistance(child.val().lat, child.val().lng);
        } else {
          distance = "Online";
        }
        tasks.push({
          title: child.val().title,
          budget: child.val().budget,
          offersCount: child.val().offersCount,
          commentsCount: child.val().commentsCount,
          distance: distance
        });
      });
      tasks.reverse();
      this.setState({
        dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(tasks)
      });
    });
  }
```

This is my bad try to implement redux in a very simple way, but I got an error: "Expected listener to be a function"

```
import { createStore } from "redux";

const reducer = (state = [], action) => {
  if (action.type === "getCurrentLocation") {
    return action.payload;
  }
  return state;
};
const store = createStore(reducer);

class TaskBrowseScreen extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    store.dispatch({ type: "getCurrentLocation", payload: "?" });
    store.subscribe();
...
```

Comment: Not on a computer so can't answer, but initial hunch is that this is probably because you are firing `listenForTasks` right after `getCurrentLocation`. This is problematic because you're doing a lot of async stuff in `getCurrentLocation` so there's no guarantee that your state will have the data you expect by time `listenForTasks` is called. This is a common problem that shows up a lot, [for example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49797939/this-props-children-map-at-react-native-is-not-working/49798184#49798184).

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you should not do it in the `componentWillMount` => [why? manual](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount)

Your issue appears because of you did not chain your calls. It will be better to call `getDistance` just after setting a location from `geolocation`:

the simplest way is to return a promise:

```
constructor() {
  super();

  this.getCurrentLocation().then(() => {
    this.listenForTasks();
  });
}

getCurrentLocation() {
  let resolver;
  let rejector;
  const promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolver = resolve;
    rejector = reject;
  });
  var loc;
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    position => {
      console.log("Location Request - Position = " + position);
      this.setState({
        latitude: position.coords.latitude,
        longitude: position.coords.longitude
      }, resolver);
    },
    error => this.setState({ error: error.message }, rejector),
    { enableHighAccuracy: false, timeout: 200000, maximumAge: 1000 }
  );

  return promise;
}
```

UPD:
It`s may be important to you, do not spend time to chaining expectation all async methods one after another. Than you can store the promise and make a chain just before call `getDistance`:

```
constructor() {
  super();

  this._promise = this.getCurrentLocation();
  this.listenForTasks();
}

listenForTasks() {
  // some async
    this._promise.then(() => {
      this.getDistance();
    });
}
```

It will may you do not spend time and call db.call in parallel.

Comment: Can you modify your answer to only call once "getCurrentLocation" ? Because otherwise it will get called over 1000 times, because of my data. This is not a real solution to my problem. My problem is that the state of latitude and longitude is null on calling "getDistance" from an async task.

Comment: I gave you an answer to "why it happens" and "how to avoid it" questions.
It does not matter how many times the `getCurrentLocation` will be called. If you need it once, you can do it on many ways depends on your app architecture and your business logic.

Comment: As I see now, `getCurrentLocation` is called in the `constructor`, it should be called once. If you need to use several components like this, you probably should make more complex solution.